# Cannot Resolve symbol class RoutingListener

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

Am doing code for Mapview to get directions by search the two locations.but am getting the error for RoutingListener. Is there any jar file for this. Please give me suggestions. wherever routing is there am getting error.Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

```
public class MapView2 extends AppCompatActivity implements RoutingListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {
protected GoogleMap map;
protected LatLng start;
protected LatLng end;
@InjectView(R.id.start)
AutoCompleteTextView starting;
@InjectView(R.id.destination)
AutoCompleteTextView destination;
@InjectView(R.id.send)
ImageView send;
private static final String LOG_TAG = "MyActivity";
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter mAdapter;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private ArrayList<Polyline> polylines;
private static final int[] COLORS = new int[]{R.color.primary_dark, R.color.primary, R.color.primary_light, R.color.accent, R.color.primary_dark_material_light};


private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_JAMAICA = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(-57.965341647205726, 144.9987719580531),
        new LatLng(72.77492067739843, -9.998857788741589));

/**
 * This activity loads a map and then displays the route and pushpins on it.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapview2);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    polylines = new ArrayList<>();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    MapsInitializer.initialize(this);
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    if (mapFragment == null) {
        mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, mapFragment).commit();
    }
    map = mapFragment.getMap();

    mAdapter = new PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            mGoogleApiClient, BOUNDS_JAMAICA, null);
```

Comment: can you please add code ?

Comment: yes i edit my question

Comment: You need to create RoutingListesner interface. Please check [this](https://github.com/jd-alexander/Google-Directions-Android/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/directions/route/RoutingListener.java) link. Also check [this](https://github.com/jd-alexander/Google-Directions-Android) project for more help.

Comment: ok have to create an interface of RoutingListener and then have to add

Comment: but after that Routingexception also shows an eror in interface

Answer (score 1):

Look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

**using intent**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=xx.xx,xx.xx&daddr=xx.xx,xx.xx"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: example here http://www.anddev.org/google_driving_directions_-_mapview_overlayed-t826.html

Comment: no am getting error for RoutingListener wherever routing is der it shows in red color.

Comment: I have given suggestion for implemetation of google map in my answer that will be more helpfull and easy way.

Answer (score 0):

[Enabled Google Libraries Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKVHu.png)

These APIs/Libraries are compulsory for routing.